# Joomla : XML: failed to load external entity

Tags: xml, joomla2.5, joomla-module

i created a new contact module for joomla 2.5.14 . when i tried to install it the system return this error : XML: failed to load external entity. here is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension
type="module"
version="2.5"
client="site"
method="upgrade">
<name>mod_mycontact</name>
<author>SmartImpact</author>
<creationDate>July 2013</creationDate>
<copyright>Copyright (C) 2012 - 2013 SmartImpact. All rights reserved.</copyright>
<license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later;</license>
<authorEmail>info@smartimpact.tn</authorEmail>
<version>2.5.14</version>
<description>MOD_MYCONTACT_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
<files>
    <filename module="mod_mycontact">mod_mycontact.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <folder>tmpl</folder>
    <filename>mod_mycontact.xml</filename>
</files>
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="email_config" label="Email Sending config">
            <field name="sender_name" type="text" label="Nom de l'expéditeur" description="Exp : Andree NAYMAR" />
            <field name="sender_email" type="text" label="Email de l'expéditeur" description="Exp : koko@gmail.com" />
            <field name="receiver_email" type="text" label="Email du récepteur" description="Exp : hello@live.fr" />            
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>    
</extension>
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking syntax error of xml file, open it into browser. if there is any Typo then it will not open properly.

I Think you do not have to include "mod_mycontact.xml".